# What's the difference between $E=\frac{F}{q}$ and $E=\frac{kQ}{r^2} $?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, coulombs-law

Can $E=\frac{kQ}{r^2}$ only be applied to situations outside of parallel plates?

Comment: What exactly about e.g. the Wikipedia article about [Coulomb's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coulomb%27s_law) is unclear to you?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Answer (score 1):

In classical mechanics, all physical interactions are said to happen through collusions. According to Coulomb's law, the force seems to be magically acting from a distance, i.e: a charge at one location influences another charge far away from it without coming into contact with it. For the early scientific age, this seemed to be impossible and there was a need for an explaination.

To solve the problem, the concept of field was introduced. The field is said to be a property of the space. A charge placed in space produces an electric field around it.

[image]

*The lines in the picture are known as electric field lines. Electric field lines are a graphical construct which is used visualize electric fields. The density of the field lines indicate the magnitude of the field and the direction of the field is along the line. By convention, electric field lines leave a positive charge and end on a negative charge*

The magnitude of electric field at a point due to a point charge is given by,
$$\vec{E} = \frac{kQ}{r^2}\hat{r}$$

The direction of the electric field at a point is along the line joining the point and the charge which is producing it.

When you bring another charge to a region in space where an electric field exists, it experiences a force, **not because of the charge** which produced it rather because of the electric field it created. In other words, we say that a charge expierences a force in the presence of an electric field.

The force expierenced by the charge in the electric field is given by,

$$\vec{F} = \vec{E}q$$

Note that the force acts on the charge along the direction of the electric field in case of positive charges and in the opposite direction in case of a negative charge.

Combining the two equations, you get coulomb's law,

$$F = Eq = \frac{kQ}{r^2}q$$

Regarding the parallel plates, we make use of electric field beause its simply far easier to deal with. In fact, the electric field which exists between two parallel plates is produced by the many charges which exist on the plates.

To sumarize, electric field is a mathematical construct which is used to explain how a charge at one point influences a charge somewhere else without touching. Electric fields and coulomb's law are mathematically equivalent. Electric field theory is an explaination for the action at distance forces whereas coulomb's law is an emperical formula.

A force between two point charges, say A and B, is said to happen this way according to the field theory,

Charge A is placed at a location >> Charge A creates an electric field around it >> Charge B enters the region of electric field and interacts with the field and expierences a force

Answer (score 0):

$\underline{F}=Q*\underline{E}$ is valid for all situations, but $E=\frac{kq}{r^2}$ is just valid for point charges.